# How to Sign out specific user after his role changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

On my project I'm working on, an Admin can delete comments which were posted by a User. When the comment is deleted, I call a function to check wether the user still has enough comments to access a specific part of the site.

If the user does not have enough comments, his role changes and this method is called:

```
    public void AfterRoleChanges(string c)
    {
        var authenticationManager = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var user = UserManager.FindById(c);
        var identity = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, identity);
    }
```

Where c = userId. But the problem with this is that if the Admin clicks the delete button, the admin gets logged out and logged in as that user, because of the authenticationmanager getting called only from the 'Current' context.

Is there a way to get the authenticationmanager of a specific userId?

Comment: I have a feeling that you're going quite a way astray here. How could someone log out another user from someone's own session? The user is still *authenticated*, removing a role has to do with *authorization*. You have to make sure that the user will notice they aren't *authorized* any more for some functions when they're removed from the role. Maybe you can give them a decent message in such cases.

Comment: @GertArnold When adding a role to a user, the role doesn't update automatically. You first have to log out and back in to get the new role. That's why I was wondering for a method that lets users log out and login immediatly whenever their role was changed.

Comment: Yes, and I say: they can only notice that by changed authorization. You can't ever (for example) delete their local authentication token/cookie. And why should they know anyway? Maybe they can keep doing what they're doing at that moment because the authorization doesn't change there.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current has a type of HttpContext. You can define a list, or a dictionary in a static class to store contexts on logon and throw them away on logout. By accessing the list you can access all users and search them as wanted.

**It's suggested to use Dictionary as you can store contexts with userIDs as keys.**

Hope it helped.